# Intent presented in the whole screen

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to display a chart in an application, which has two tabs. The main class in the `onCreate()` method instantiates the two tabs, associated with the corresponding classes. The second tab has to present the chart. The chart's class isn't an Activity, it has a method, which returns an Intent, and this is presented in an Activity class.

My problem is, if I tap on the chart tab, the chart is presented on the whole screen, not only under the two tab buttons. What should I modify?

Here is a short structure:

The main class:

```
public class CurrencyTabActivity extends TabActivity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Resources res = getResources(); 
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 
        TabHost.TabSpec spec; 
        Intent intent; 

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, CurrencyListActivity.class);

        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("currency").setIndicator("",
                res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_currency))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, GraphActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("graph").setIndicator("",
                res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_graph))
                .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

The class which has to present the chart:

```
public class GraphActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent;
        TemperatureChart tc = new TemperatureChart();
        intent = tc.execute(this);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And the chart class:

```
public class TemperatureChart{
//................
public Intent execute(Context context){ 
//...................................
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TemperatureChart intent presented as its own `Activity` outside of the tabs because you haven't added it to the `TabHost`. You're simply launching an `Activity`... Why can't you just make the TemperatureChart an Activity and add it to the `TabHost`?